Alphabetical Scroll Bar in Angular 17 (standalone) and Ionic v8
how can I use this cool alphabetical scrollbar in Angular 17 Standalone?
https://github.com/mooalot/alphabetical-scroll-bar
I upgraded my project to standalone and I don't have any NGModules....
Or does anyone know another way/component for a standalone application?
Thank you already

The library is not compatible with higher versions of Angular compiler engine ivy, so it's not possible to use it, else you want to use a older version of Angular.
You can raise a issue on their GitHub to update for later versions of Angular.
Also please look for alternative packages.
✘ [ERROR] TS-996003: 'AlphabeticalScrollBarModule' does not appear to be an NgModule, Component, Directive, or Pipe class. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/main.ts:11:4:
      11 │     AlphabeticalScrollBarModule
         ╵     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  This likely means that the library (alphabetical-scroll-bar) which
  declares AlphabeticalScrollBarModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy.
  Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so.
  Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library 
  is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

Not working Stackblitz
